# Approach for mapping web service classes to local client classes

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have Java web serivce and .NET client application that consume this web service. When we connect to the service we generate service classes (serialization) in our project. But using this web service classes in code directly is wrong approach. I have some ideas about how to create and map my local class to web service class. But I am intertested in how others do the same staff in their applications.

If you have ability pls show your approach in code.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for Facade and Adapter. You will create Facade on your proxy classes the facade will transform service classes to your classes and vice-versa. If you have easy mapping you can use some automatic approach (AutoMapper).